# Android custom toolbar menu item title color and style

Tags: android, customization, android-toolbar

I am drawing a custom toolbar which needs to be displayed at the bottom of the screen i.e. it is not the action bar.

Now, I have a toolbar and a custom menu.

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item 
          android:title="@string/get_directions"
          app:showAsAction="always|withText"
          android:icon="@drawable/navigation_icon/>
</menu>
```

toolbar layout inside a linear layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

I use toolbar.inflatemenu() to inflate the above menu. Now, I want to customize the appearance (like color, font etc) of the menu item title. Is there any way to do that except using actionlayout in the menuitem?

Please note that its not an "action bar". All the solutions i found on internet are for action bars. Please suggest something for standalone toolbars.

Comment: You can style same way actoinbar but need to use app compat parent styles, see:http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: So, in the link there is no mention of how can we change the color of "Text"

Comment: Its just reference for more see https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html As I said you can use actionbar style with proper app compat parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create new style in themes.xml or style.xml

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
         ...
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/your_color</item>
         ...
 </style>
```

Now apply style to your toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
/>
```

Comment: my question is, as this is not action bar, why do we need to event set DarkActionBar as the parent of the style?

Comment: All styles are inherited from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and overridden by ToolbarStyle. You can simply delete that if you dont want to borrow style from parent theme

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The styling didn't work for me, so I used:

```
public static void applyFontForToolbarTitle(Activity context){
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) context.findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    for(int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++){
        View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
        if(view instanceof TextView){
            TextView tv = (TextView) view;
            Typeface titleFont = Typeface.
               createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/customFont");
            if(tv.getText().equals(context.getTitle())){
                tv.setTypeface(titleFont);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```